# How to make the parent height wrap the content height?

Tags: css

I wrote this css example, it works fine if the content is not much in number

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
        html{
            height:100%;
            margin:0px;
        }
        body{
            height:100%;
            margin:0px;
        }
        div{
            height:100%;
            margin:0px;
            background-color:red;
            width:100%;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div>
            <p style="height:300px;width:100px; background-color:blue;margin:0px;">content</p>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

But my example fails as soon as you add more content

```
<div>
   <p style="height:300px;width:100px; background-color:blue;margin:0px;">content</p>
   <p style="height:300px;width:100px; background-color:blue;margin:0px;">content</p>
   <p style="height:300px;width:100px; background-color:blue;margin:0px;">content</p>
</div>
```

[image]

How do I write some css to wrap the content when the content is in a greater number?

Comment: instead of `height: 100%` on `div`, use `min-height: 100%`?

Comment: You don't have to put `height: 100%` to all `<div>`. It's forcing all `<div>` to be at 100% height. That's why the red `<div>`'s height is set at 100% of screen

Comment: Please provide a clearer explanation of what you are trying to achieve. Read it 5 times, and still not sure of what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to achieve this: If blue content height < browser height, then red div height = browser height. If blue content height > browser height, then red div height = blue content height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make your html's height 100%, it will scale the body tag to the 100%, limiting the div's height ultimately, to work around this problem, you have two approaches.

### Approach 1

Apply `height 100%` only to the body tag

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0px;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
        
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div>
            <p style="height:300px;width:100px; background-color:blue;margin:0px;">content</p>
            <p style="height:300px;width:100px; background-color:blue;margin:0px;">content</p>
            <p style="height:300px;width:100px; background-color:blue;margin:0px;">content</p>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

### Approach 2

Add `overflow:auto` to your div to make it's overflow automatic and based on the content, like

```css
body,html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0px;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  overflow:auto;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
        
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div>
            <p style="height:300px;width:100px; background-color:blue;margin:0px;">content</p>
            <p style="height:300px;width:100px; background-color:blue;margin:0px;">content</p>
            <p style="height:300px;width:100px; background-color:blue;margin:0px;">content</p>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Approach 2 is work, Approach 1 is not work, in approach 1, red div is not fill the height of browser

Comment: for approach 1, remove the html tag from css

Answer (score 0):

Fixed widths and fixed heights don't work for modern responsive layouts. If you provide us with more specific information on the widths of the columns in percentages of the viewport width, I will update this answer with a tried-and-true approach to equal height columns.